# How to save update in json (file.json) with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file and am trying to update it through jQuery but the problem is I can't save the update after the script is done.

How can I save the update but without any server side scripting?

The JSON file `data.json`:

```
{"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"Ray",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "joined": {
            "month":"January",
            "day":12,
            "year":2012
        }
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "joined": {
            "month":"April",
            "day":28,
            "year":2010
        }
    }
]}
```

HTML file:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data)
    {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.users)
        {
            data.users[0].firstName = "Saleh";

            output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " 
                    + data.users[i].lastName + "--" 
                    + data.users[i].joined.month+"</li>";
        }
        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you edit a json file stored on the server from jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

You mean you want to update a file on the server with javascript? It's not possible without writing any server side code. That would be a huge security hole.

You can't let client to change anything on the server without performing any server-side checks.